# How to push different grouping keys each to pushgateway in spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch, prometheus, spring-actuator, prometheus-pushgateway, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I am running a Job on multiple nodes using Spring batch.

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.3.2'
implementation 'io.prometheus:simpleclient_pushgateway:0.9.0'
```

And basically, PushGateway's grouping key is used as `host` and `job name`.

And while maintaining the above metrics,
I want to create a logic that is sent once again by excluding the `host` from the grouping key and configuring it only with the `job name`.

for example
When A Job is executed, we want to have two Groups in PushGateway.
Group1 - `host=node1`, `jobName=A Job`
Group2 - `jobName=A Job`

I wonder if this is possible and how do you think about it?

Comment: `And basically, PushGateway's grouping key is used as host and job name.`: Where is that configured? This is where you should be able to exclude `host`.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine  

Set in `management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.grouping-key`.  
There are a few more group keys, but for brevity, I've written the question with only job name and host .

I want to create two PushGateways with different group keys in one app and send data.
So I was wondering if it is possible in libardy for spring actuator etc.

Comment: I think you need to do it programmatically then, meaning configuring your PushGateway yourself as needed. I'm not sure there is a way to do that declaratively with a property.